# Grub Cannot load Ubuntu

Tags: boot, grub2, wubi

My computer refused load Ubuntu and instead gave me grub. When I typed `boot`, it said you need to load the kernel first. I saw some other stuff on grub so I have tried find /boot/grub/stage1 but it gives me an error (can't find command 'find').

If it matters, I believe this error was caused by a startup repair from Windows (which I think affects the disk) so if anyone can help me.

Comment: What version of Ubuntu are you using? Did you install it using Wubi, the Windows installer?

Answer (score 0):

Running a Windows Startup Repair is definitely quite risky on Linux systems. You can mess up any number of things including the MBR and boot sector.

Fortunately, there is a tool out there designed to easily recover from this type of issue called Boot-repair. All you need is an Ubuntu Live CD or USB and an internet connection. See the [Boot-repair guide in the Ubuntu Community Documentation](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair#A2nd_option_%3a_install_Boot-Repair_in_Ubuntu) to see how to install the tool in a live environment, and then just do a Recommended Repair. If you run into further issues, it will create a Boot Info Script link which you can paste back here.

Comment: What if I don't have a Live CD?

Comment: @jt1250champ Live USB?

Comment: I don't have that either?

Comment: @jt1250champ how did you install Ubuntu?

Comment: From the Ubuntu website downloaded while on windows

Comment: If you don't have a CD or USB with Ubuntu, you can try one of the methods listed here: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation#Installation_without_a_CD Although I am not familiar with any of those methods.